# Regex to match a pattern but not two specific cases

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to match every cases of `"-"`, but not these ones:

1. `[\d]-[A-Z]`
2. `[A-Z]-[\d]`

I tried this pattern: `((?<![A-Z])-(?![0-9]))|((?<![0-9])-(?![A-Z]))` but some results are incorrect like: "RUA VF-32 N"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean `\B-|-\B`?

Comment: what if their data has something like the word "sub-optimal"? Not that they'd want to remove the - there, but based on their requirements it seems like they would.

Comment: What language/library/tool are you using? What results are you getting and how are they incorrect (what did you expect instead)?

Comment: I'm using R. I wanted to match cases like "QUADRA 120 - ASA BRANCA" and "FAZENDA LAGE -RODOVIA RIO VERDE", but not "C-15" ou "99-B". "VF-32" is incorrect because "F-3" should not match.

Comment: So, try `grep("\\B-|-\\B", x)`

Comment: Wiktor, the problem is that it will not match cases like "A-A", that is are necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is to use `grep` with your current logic and inverting the result, and then run another grep to only keep those items that have a hyphen in them:

```
x <- c("QUADRA 120 - ASA BRANCA","FAZENDA LAGE -RODOVIA RIO VERDE","C-15","99-B","A-A")
grep("-", grep("[A-Z]-\\d|\\d-[A-Z]", x, invert=TRUE, value=TRUE), value=TRUE, fixed=TRUE)
# => [1] "QUADRA 120 - ASA BRANCA"         "FAZENDA LAGE -RODOVIA RIO VERDE"
#    [3] "A-A"
```

Here, `[A-Z]-\\d|\\d-[A-Z]` matches a hyphen either in between an uppercase ASCII etter or a digit or betweena digit and an ASCII uppercase letter. If there is a match, the result is inverted due to `invert=TRUE`.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/TRKCx1).

To only match `-` in all contexts other than in between a letter and a digit, you may use the PCRE regex based on [SKIP-FAIL technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) like

```
> grep("(?:\\d-[A-Z]|[A-Z]-\\d)(*SKIP)(*F)|-", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] 1 2
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QoOyOX/2)

**Details**

- `(?:\d-[A-Z]|[A-Z]-\d)` - a non-capturing group that matches either a digit, `-` and then uppercase ASCII letter, or an uppercase ASCII letter, `-` and a digit
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - omit the current match and proceed looking for the next match at the end of the "failed" match
- `|` - or
- `-` - a hyphen.

Comment: Great! Thank you!